# How to get abstract class constructor value in derived class

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class

How to get abstract class constructor value in derived class.

```
   public abstract class ABC
        {
            private string data = "hi";

            protected ABC(string myString)
            {
                myString = data;
            }
        }
        public class XYZ: ABC
        {
            public string abc= "";
            public XYZ(string myString)
                : base(myString)
            {
                abc = myString;
            }
        }

          XYZ var = new XYZ("567");
          Response.Write(var.abc);
```

I am getting 567 as output , how to get "hi567" or "567hi" or even "hi".

Comment: This appears to depend entirely on the exact implementation/syntax of the language. Is this Java?

Comment: I've re-tagged the question for you. Please remember that this site accepts questions for any programming language or technology thus you have to use tags to specify them.

Comment: Please give a real-world example of what you are trying to accomplish. This seems like a very strange thing to be trying to do.

Comment: I started writing an answer but then I relaised I have no idea what your trying to acomplish. Please explain better.

Comment: I just want to know, can I get the abstract class constructor value in derived class??, If yes then how?

Comment: what shoild i write in place of  "XYZ var = new XYZ("567");
          Response.Write(var.abc);"

Comment: You can't get hold of private fields in the base class without mucking around with reflection. You shouldn't do that either. Instead you should make the value(s) in the base class available to derived classes so that the derived class constructor has access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple - but kinda weird:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var var = new XYZ("567");
            Console.WriteLine(var.abc);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public abstract class ABC
    {
        private string data = "hi";

        protected ABC(string myString, out string outString)
        {
            myString = this.data;
            outString = myString;
        }
    }

    public class XYZ : ABC
    {
        public string abc = "";

        public XYZ(string myString) : this(myString, string.Empty)
        {
        }

        private XYZ(string myString, string outString) : base(myString, out outString)
        {
            this.abc = outString + myString;
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to pass an out-parameter to the base constructor.

Comment: I was also thinking `out` parameter, and also thinking "weird". In the abstract class, the constructor does not really need the first parameter, so use `protected ABC(out string outString) { outString = data; }`

Comment: passing ref or out parameters to a constructor is ugly

Answer (score 0):

This is something that gives the output you want, but not sure though what's in your mind -

```
    public abstract class ABC
    {
        private string data = "hi ";

        protected ABC(string myString)
        {
            data += myString;
        }

        public string PropToReturnValuePassedInCtor{ get { return data; } }
    }

    public class XYZ: ABC
    {
        public string abc = "";

        public XYZ(string myString)
            : base(myString)
        {
            abc = base.PropToReturnValuePassedInCtor;
        }
    }

    var t = new XYZ("567");
    Console.Write(t.abc); //hi 567
```

Comment: I think the questioner wants to keep `data` private and does not want to expose it via a property.

Comment: @PeterPerot - if OP wants to hide it, why access it at all?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Don't know. Anyway - it's considered bad practice to use constructors with out parameters. I never had to use it, but however - it can be done.

Comment: if you want to expose some data that's private to a class, use properties.

Comment: ... *protected* properties - otherwise it's visible from the outside.